# Weyl group Invariants

Tags: algebraic-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory

What are the generators of $\mathbb C[V^m]^W$, where $W$ is the Weyl group
of type $E_6, E_7, E_8$, V^m denote 'm' (m > 1) copies of the Cartan subalgebra 
and the action is the diagonal action?

Is there any reference where I can find the generators explicitly?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on generators that you want? Why exceptional types? This is a very hard problem even for $A_n$ (symmetric group), at least, if you want a minimal system of generators.  

Comment: Looks like another shooter in the dark...

Comment: When m=1, if the Weyl group is from a classical Lie algebra then this is a known result, and it is not hard to imagine that somewhere the case of m copies has been worked out. I suspect this is why the asker is more interested in exceptional type.

Comment: No, any system of generator will work for me, not necessarily a minimal system. For type $A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n$ and $G_2$ I know a set of generators but I do not have any clue for other exceptional types.
Actually I am much more interested in the degrees of the generators.

Comment: @Q.Q.J. Could you please give me a reference for you claim concerning the case $m=1$?

Comment: Lepanais: If I recall correctly it is the combination of  Chevalley's Theorem and the First Fundamental Theorem of Invariant Theory for the Classical groups. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answer is known.  The paper [Hunziker, Classical invariant theory for finite reflection groups. Transform. Groups 2 (1997), no. 2, 147–163] is relevant.  The author conjectures an answer and shows his answer is correct for $F_4$.